# Set foreign key value in business entity data model

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have table SublocationTbl that have SubLocationName and LocationId(this field is foreign key from table LocationTbl), and I have business entity data model
I know that the foreign key dosen't appear in the business entity
my problrm is: how can I set the value of locationId when I need to add new subLocation?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...?

```
using(var db = new myDbContext())
{
    var myNewSubLocation = new SubLocation();
    myNewSubLocation.LocationID = 12345; //put ur value here

    db.SubLocations.Add(myNewSubLocation);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that locationId is foreign key and it dosen't appear in sublocations business entity so myNewSubLocation.LocationID  not exist

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to see the foreign key it self you must use .NET framework 4 not less in .NET 3.5 you'll find a reference to foreign key's class not the foreign key it self

`Store s = new Store();
                User u=s.User;//bring referance of the user with foreign key .net 3.5 & 4
                int i = s.User_ID;//bring the user_id forein key .net 4`